# New Object missing if not using Data Provider - Audit.Net

Tags: c#, audit.net

I notice the `AuditScope` got `.Event` properties which contains the value the event logs. So it can convert to json by using this command

```
var Scope = AuditScope.Create("Account:Suspend", () => user);

//Change value properties on user object
//Save into database

//Retrieve eventlog from audit
var EventInJson = Scope.Event.ToJson();
```

So I decide to not use CustomDataProvider, so I configure Audit.Net like this

`Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup();`

But the `New Object` was missing inside the `Target Object`. Sample result

`{
  "EventType": "Account:Suspend",
  "Environment": {
    "UserName": "test",
    "MachineName": "test",
    "DomainName": "test",
    "CallingMethodName": "Account.API.Controllers.AccountController+<UpdateSuspend>d__35.MoveNext()",
    "AssemblyName": "Account.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "Culture": "en-MY"
  },
  "Target": {
    "Type": "ApplicationUser",
    "Old": {
      "CountryId": 1,
      "IsDeleted": false,
      "IsSuspend": true,
      "RiskLevelId": 0,
      "CreationDate": "2018-10-05T04:51:32.485",
      "LastLoginDate": "2018-10-05T04:51:32.486",
      "Id": 23,
      "UserName": "user",
      "NormalizedUserName": "test",
      "Email": "test@test.com",
      "NormalizedEmail": "test@test.com",
      "EmailConfirmed": false,
      "SecurityStamp": "Test",
      "ConcurrencyStamp": "test",
      "PhoneNumberConfirmed": false,
      "TwoFactorEnabled": false,
      "LockoutEnd": "2018-12-18T04:15:56.2490628+00:00",
      "LockoutEnabled": false,
      "AccessFailedCount": 0
    }
  },
  "StartDate": "2019-01-08T09:35:34.8363926Z",
  "Duration": 0
}`

Is possible to use without data provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `New` value is missing because it's updated when the scope is **Saved**, depending on the creation policy it could be when the scope is disposed, or when you explicitly call the `Save` method on the `AuditScope`. So after you modify the target object and before you get the auditevent, you have to dispose the scope or call its `Save` method.

Also note that calling like this `Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup();` is not enough to have a NULL data provider, that code will just let the default which is the `FileDataProvider`. In order to specify a NULL data provider you can do `Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup().UseNullProvider();`

Comment: After configure user null provider, no more json file created. And .Save() method is working. Thanks creator, great library